2009 Hyundai i20 1st/2nd gear issues - feels like it will stall and shudders, before running normally
2009 i20 petrol manual with intermittent power loss in 1st/2nd gears (no issues in higher gears)
When pulling off in 1st gear, car feels like it will stall shuddering and loses power.
2nd gear can have the same issue too if going at very slow speed, need to rev through to get going.
No engine lights are on - putting car into neutral alleviates feeling of resistance.
Issue only occurs at start up / low gear / low speed and only happens at beginning of journey, never happens when pulling off from stationary mid journey (e.g. from standstill at lights)
Revving through resistance/ just lifting the clutch as normal reduces the shuddering, and it doesn't stall
This seems to be a commonly reported issue - however, the root cause is unclear.
Does anyone have any ideas what could be causing this?
